# How to connect X11 to virtual box?

Tags: x11-forwarding

I noticed that there is a way to control the ubuntu installed in virtual box using X11 in Window. My eclipse was running quite unsmoothly in virtual box. Therefore, I want to use X11 to help me programming better. But I don't know how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you forward X11 and run Eclipse in VirtualBox you will almost certainly experience worse issues. X11 forwarding means that everything that was running in VirtualBox is still running in VirtualBox except now it's sent through a network connection to the host you're on. If you want to try it use this with ssh

```
ssh -X username@domain.com
```

then open the tool from the prompt and see if it helps. You may need to enable X11 from the `sshd_config` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the VirtualBox.